# Concatenated number fields in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 2 number fields in crystal reports that I want to concatenate using a formula field, so in my formula I created a field and added `ToText({Table.TOTAL_QTY}) & " / " & ToText({Table.BOX_COUNT})` as the formula. Works fine but the numbers appear with decimals, "9.00 / 12.00". How do I remove the 0's in the formula field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToText` supports various formatting options. You can pass the number of decimals in the second parameter when the first parameter is a number:

```
ToText({Table.TOTAL_QTY}, 0) & " / " & ToText({Table.BOX_COUNT}, 0)
```

From Crystal Reports 2008: The Complete Reference:

> **ToText (n1, n2, s1, s2)**
>   n1 – a numeric value to be converted to a string.
>   n2 – a numeric value indicating the number of decimal places to use when converting n1.
>   This argument is optional.
>   s1 – a string value indicating the character or characters to use as a thousands separator
>   when converting n1. This argument is optional.
>   s2 – a string value indicating the character or characters to use as a decimal separator when
>   converting n1. This argument is optional.